# AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'coef_'

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I am self-studying machine learning and python. I am using sklearn and I want to plot the regression line, but I get the attributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'coef_. Could somebody help me to fix it, thank you in advance.

```
x=data['size']
y=data['price']
x_matrix=x.values.reshape(-1,1)
reg=LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_matrix,y)
plt.scatter(x,y)
yhat= reg.coef_ * x_matrix + reg.intercept_
fig=plt.plot(x, yhat, lw=4, c="orange", label="regression line")
plt.xlabel("size", fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("price", fontsize=20)
plt.show() 
 
AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'coef_
```

Comment: What makes you think `reg` has an attribute `coef_`?

Comment: @Scott Hunter Sorry, I do not get what you exactly mean, what I did is to fit reg and as we can have the coefficient and the intercept by reg.coef_ and reg.intercept_, then I think we can plot it. But I get that error. I am so sorry if my explanation is not so clear I am new to the subject and I self-study.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @ScottHunter There should be a `coef_` attribute for the model at least per sklearn docs (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

Answer (score 0):

The code provided doesn't yield any attribute error. However, the `coef_` attribute is only created when the `fit()` method is called. Before that, it will be `undefined`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646040/attributeerror-linearregression-object-has-no-attribute-coef).

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['size', 'price'])

x=data['size']
y=data['price']
x_matrix=x.values.reshape(-1,1)

reg=LinearRegression()
# make sure to call fit
reg.fit(x_matrix,y)
yhat= reg.coef_ * x_matrix + reg.intercept_
```

Comment: But they do call `fit`, right? `reg.fit(x_matrix,y); plt.scatter(x,y); yhat= reg.coef_ * x_matrix + reg.intercept_`.

Comment: Downvoted because the code is simply a repetition of OP's code, but with a different example.